# How can I get the Agent Smith ReSharper plugin to recognize that Status is not plural

Tags: enums, naming-conventions, resharper

When using the Agent Smith plugin for ReSharper, I get the warning "Enums that are not flags should not have plural names" for an enum that ends in Status. For example:

```
public enum SomeStatus
{
    Success,
    Failed
}
```

In fact Status is not plural, so this isn't really in violation of the naming rule. I found [this ticket](http://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/issues/detail?id=64) from 2008 bringing up the issue, but it doesn't look like it has been fixed.

Is there any clever way to work around this (e.g. some kind of custom configurable regex)?